# MySQL how to group by a column and make some of the values go into 1 row

Tags: mysql, group-by, grouping, mysql-workbench

I want to use a GROUP BY function to group a column, and take several values in that column and aggregate them all together into 1 row in the result.
Example:

Table:

[image]

Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(device_id), version FROM MyTable GROUP BY version;
```

Result:

[image]

Desired result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could construct the two results:

```
  SELECT COUNT(device_id) as version_count, 
         version 
  FROM MyTable 
  WHERE version IN ('3.0.3','3.0.2','2.9.5')
  GROUP BY version
  UNION
  SELECT COUNT(device_id) as version_count, 
         'Others' 
  FROM MyTable 
  WHERE version NOT IN ('3.0.3','3.0.2','2.9.5');
```

The select statement left of the union operator counts the device ids by version for the three given versions in the example. The select statement right from the union operator counts the device ids for all other versions (not the three versions given).

Comment: #Mithrandir that works great! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You've not told us what your criteria are for deciding if a particular row should be aggregated as 'other' so as it stands you are not going to get a definitive answer.

There are 2 likely scenarios I can imagine - that you want to decompose based on the size of the value or its frequency. If you can define a query which returns EITHER the data you want to group as "other" OR the data you want listed individually then join this back to your original dataset.....

```
 SELECT version, COUNT(*)
 FROM myTable
 GROUP BY version
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
 LIMIT 0,3
```

gives you the most popular 3 versions, OTOH...

```
 SELECT version
 FROM myTable
 ORDER BY version DESC
 LIMIT 0,3
```

will give you the most recent version (although you will run into issues as there is [no simple way](http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php) I know of to handle a multi-decimal version number in MySQL - consider version 3.0.9 vs 3.0.200)

hence...

```
SELECT IFNULL(ilv.version, "other"), COUNT(*)
FROM myTable m
LEFT JOIN (
         SELECT version, COUNT(*)
         FROM myTable
         ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
         LIMIT 0,3
) ilv
ON m.version=ilv.version
GROUP BY IFNULL(ilv.version, "other")
```

There are a couple of significantly more efficient ways to get the result (the above requires 2 full passes through the data) but using the LEFT JOIN / sub-query approach simplifies the task of redefining the "other" classification.